# Is the expression « Ça n’est pas pour me déplaire ! » an understatement?

Tags: litote

> Nous voilà enfin à deux doigts de mettre la main sur une Mercedes ! ***Ça n’est pas pour me déplaire !***

I wonder if the speaker is actually thrilled to bits at the idea, although the expression (if taken literally) does not indicate that he is overly excited –  but rather only moderately so. Is it perhaps similar to the understatement "I wouldn't complain" in English, for instance?

Incidentally, are there other commonly used understatements in French that you use to mask or tone down your excitement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes), which generally tones down the general meaning of the sentence.

However, in this context (because of the "enfin" that means here "not too soon", and the exclamation point) it is probably ironic, so the effect is the opposite of the attenuation of the litotes!

The end result is that the speaker is actually excited by the announcement.
It also means he was not happy before that: he's clearly turning from unhappy to excited (he was "displeased", that's why he's now "not displeased" instead of "pleased").

Answer (score 1):

La plus connue des litotes je pense :

> Va, je ne te hais point.

Dans *Le cid* de Corneille. C'est Chimène qui parle à Rodrigue. Elle lui dirait bien qu'elle l'aime mais c'est compliqué puisqu'il vient de tuer son père. :) Elle l'aime à la folie.
Ou encore:

> Notre adieu ne fut point un adieu d'ennemis.

Et oui, ils s'aiment toujours passionnément.

La litote est **plus** qu'une simple atténuation (understatement ?). Une atténuation est un *euphémisme*:

> Oui, j'ai un peu fumé aujourd'hui.

oh, un petit paquet de cigarettes... Ou encore :

> Je les ai un légèrement bousculés

quand on a dit des gros mots chez des gens bien.
Un euphémisme est une petite litote. Mais souvent, la différence est subtile et dépend du contexte. Si la dernière phrase est utilisée pour dire qu'on vient de tuer toute la famille, ça ressemble plus à une litote.